# Expressão regular para aceitar apenas números e uma ","

Tags: javascript

Como posso fazer uma expressão ou função para pegar apenas números e vírgula, que o usuário informar.

Quero pegar num formulário preços de produtos. Se o usuário digitar uma letra ou outra coisa a não ser a vírgula, não irá ser validado. Tenho o exemplo com apenas números, mas não tenho para pegar vírgula:

javascript:

```
function soNumeros(numeros) { //variavel do parametro recebe o caractere digitado//  
    return numeros.replace(/\D/g,"");  
}
```

Formulário:

```
<label="soNumeros">
    Só números: <input id="numeros" onkeypress="mascara(this, soNumeros)" maxlength="11"/>
</label>
```

Depois é só chamar a função no formulário usando onkeypress.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O `\D` não pega números, ele é a negação de `\d`, que deveria ser o correto a usar.

Para escrever mais de uma condição dentro de uma regex você deve usar `|`, ficaria algo como:

```
/\d|,/g
```

No entanto acho que você quer usar pra validar números quebrados, então se o valor for monetário, você pode usar assim:

```
/^\d+,\d{2}$/
```

### Explicando esta regex:

- As `/` são usados em toda regex no JavaScript tudo que vai dentro do `/.../` são as expressões, tudo que vai depois do segundo `/` como `g` e `i`  são os modificadores
- `^` indica que a string deve começar com qualquer expressão que vier depois dele, no caso o `\d`
- `\d+` indica que vai procurar qualquer numero até encontrar a próxima expressão que no caso é a `,`
- `{2}` diz a quantidade caracteres anteriores que deve conter
- `$` indica que a string deve terminar com os caracteres que vem antes dele.
- `\d{2}$` indica que ele vai validar a string se ele terminar com 2 caracteres numéricos.

Usando o `^` junto com o `$`, torna neste caso o modificado `g` redundante.

No entanto se você esta usando como [evento `keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event), o melhor é fazer a mascara assim:

```
/[\d,]/
```

- Os `[...]` indicam que a expressão pode conter qualquer caractere que esta dentro destas chaves.

### Extras:

- `g` é um modificador que indica global e serve como "recursividade", ou seja se usar assim `"ababab".replace(/a/, "");` o resutado vai ser `babab` pois ele remove apenas o primeiro `a` que encontrar, se fizer assim `"ababab".replace(/a/g, "");` vai resultar nisto `bbb`.
- `i` indica *case-insensitive* (não diferencia maiúsculos de minúsculos).

No entanto não é fácil aplicar mascara com *regex*, portanto você pode usar um plugin jQuery pro trabalho, como o https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney por exemplo:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="meu-input" data-thousands="" data-decimal="," />

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#meu-input').maskMoney();
});
</script>
```

Leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: O que o símbolo "/" significa? E o "\"? Pergunto porque têm os dois símbolos juntos.  

O "$" significa o que?

Rapaz, já pensei em estudar javascript, mas é um pouco complexo.

Comment: @AndréNascimento a sua pergunta foi sobre uma *regex* especifica e não sobre aprender *regex*, no entanto editei a resposta pra você ter uma ideia de onde começar.

Comment: Peguei a sua resposta e testei, mas não funcionou. Coloquei no jsfidle.  

https://jsfiddle.net/gL1uqmbu/

Comment: @AndréNascimento não funcionou porque tem erros na sintaxe e já acusou no console, fora que suas variaveis não estão definidas, vou editar a resposta. Fora um detalhe "muito" importante, você html e javascript tudo junto no fiddle dentro do campo de javascript.

Comment: A que eu costumo usar é `/[\d\.]+,\d{2}/`, para caso tenho separação no milhar.

Comment: Boa noite @GuilhermeLautert, xará ... o caso de milhar que você mostrou até funciona, mas ele aceita valores aleatórios como `1.1.1,00`, talvez se usar `?` consiga maior precisão, não sei ainda ao certo pois estou enferrujado em regex.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Veja achei este ótimo exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16148273/1518921

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento compreendo, a que comentei é uma versão mais simples e como você demostra não exata, mas essa contempla `/(\d{1,3}\.?)+,\d{2}/` seja no [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pR8vP0/1)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é esse exemplo é ainda melhor = D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert então sem querer ser chato kk ... este `/(\d{1,3}\.?)+,\d{2}/` também tem um problema, ele aceita isto `0.100.000,01`, no link este `/^(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))(?!0(?!\.))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/` não aceita começar com `0` por causa do `?!0` :) Vai depender da necessidade, mas gostei do teu exemplo se permitir começar com zero é realmente bem simples.

Answer (score 1):

```
function soNumeros(numeros)
  { /*Retorna máscara com R$*/
    numeros = numeros.replace(/\D/g, "");
    numeros = numeros.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2})/, "R\$ $1,$2");
    numeros = numeros.replace(/(R\$\s)(\d+)(\d{3})(\,\d{2})/, "$1$2.$3$4");
    numeros = numeros.replace(/(R\$\s)(\d+)(\d{3})(\.\d{3}\,\d{2})/, "$1$2.$3$4");
    numeros = numeros.replace(/(R\$\s)(\d+)(\d{3})(\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\,\d{2})/, "$1$2.$3$4");
    return numeros;  
  }
```

Até dá pra fazer com uma ou duas linhas, mas vc tem que implementar um callback no replace, tipo replace(/expressão/, function(){}).
Ou então criar uma expressão com match recursivo em grupos tipo:

```
numero = numero.replace(/(R\$\s)(\d+)(\d{3})((\.\d{3})+\.\d{3}\,\d{2})/, "$1$2.$3$4");
```

Comment: não resolveu. Quando digito as letras é validada. Mas valeu.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 /**
 全角数字・全角アルファベットを半角に変換
 Convert zenkaku to hankaku
 ie: japanese number like ０１２, will be converted to 012.
 */
 function ZenKakuToHankaku(str) {
  if (str == "") {
   return "";
  }

        //16進数の場合 (0xFEE0 supports hexadecimal)
  return str.replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function(s) {
   return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
  });
 }

 /**
 Remove non numeric characters from string.
 Parameter "add" allows to customize the rule. Example, if want allow comma or decimal point.
 */
 function NumberOnly(str, add) {
     add = (typeof add === "undefined")? "": add;
  var rule = new RegExp("[^0-9"+add+"]", "g");
  return str.replace(rule, "");
 }

 /**
 Returns only number.
 Before filter the invalid caracters, zenkaku to hankaku sanitization is executed.
 */
 function NumberFilter(n, add) {
     add = (typeof add === 'undefined')? '': add;
  n = ZenKakuToHankaku(n);
  if (n == "") {
      return "";
  }
  n = NumberOnly(n, add);
  return n;
 }

 //console.log("result: "+NumberFilter("９,6", ","));
 //console.log("result: "+NumberOnly("10aaaaaa"));

 function Sanitize() {
  obj = document.getElementById("n");
  obj.value = NumberFilter(obj.value, ",");
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" size="10" id="n" value="９,６ i y J Ad">
<input type="button" value="sanitize" onclick="Sanitize();">
```

Nesse exemplo é feito também uma sanitização de zenkaku para hankaku.

O **zenkaku 全角** são caracteres"full width" do teclado japonês.

O **hankaku 半角** são os "half width".

Veja como são diferentes

```
０１２３４５６７８９
0123456789
```

Portanto, a função `ZenKakuToHankaku()` serve para sanitizar e permitir entradas zenkaku.

A função `NumberOnly()` remove tudo que não for numérico. Por isso, `ZenKakuToHankaku()` deve ser aplicado antes.

Um outro recurso diferente das outras respostas é que a função `NumberOnly()` possui um segundo parâmetro no qual pode implementar a regra da expressão regular. Nesse caso, adicionamos o caracter vírgula `,`. Por adicionar múltiplos caracteres ou qualquer outro como o ponto `.`, hífem `-`, etc.

Dessa forma a rotina torna-se reutilizável para diferentes situações.

Answer (score 0):

Só relembro que o HTML5 já contempla algum tipo de validação de campos.

Exemplo1: Interiros enter 100 e 5000

```
<input type="number" name="n1" min="100" max="5000">
```

Exemplo2: números com (opcionalmente) duas casas opcionais:

```
<input type="text" name="n2" pattern="\d+(,\d\d)?">
```